# To see rich event data link a Truffle Project containing the contract that emits this event

Tags: events, blockchain, smartcontracts, ganache

adding the js truffle-config. js in my ganache project i can't see the saved output in my contract function, what can i do?
I get this message about the ganache event:
"To see rich event data link a Truffle Project containing the contract that emits this event"